# How to connect to a postgres pod in a k8s cluster

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, kubernetes, microservices

I have a microservice with several backends.. for mongodb I use the service to get the address of the database.. simething like this:

```
mongodb://tasksdb.default.svc.cluster.local:6004/users
```

I would like the same concept but now for postgres. I have:

```
postgis://postgres:postgres@192.168.10.10:6006/orderrs
```

How do I do this? mark you I need the port number.

Comment: What is your service arrangement for Postgres? Are you trying to access it within the cluster or externally? Some more details would be useful from kubectl.

Comment: I'm trying to access it within the cluster

Comment: Okay do you have a deployment running with a ClusterIP service etc.? Can you show the output of something like ```kubectl get svc -A``` and cover up any external IPs if shown? It's impossible to suggest something without knowing what the service setup is, where it's running and what it's called.

Answer (score 0):

postgres uri connection string - [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING)

```
postgres://user:password@host:port/dbname
```

for example :

```
postgres://admin:password@127.0.0.0:5432/postgres
```

Make sure you expose your postgers Pod internally

```
kubectl expose pod POD_NAME --port WANTED_PORT --target-port 5432
```